# Negative timestamp in db

Tags: php, timestamp

I am working with php and I need to store a `timestamp`. I read a lot about `timestamp` but i don't understand why :

```
"01/01/1970 00:04:00" = -3600
```

(source: http://www.timestamp-tool.fr/)

It should be 3600 ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a platform issue. From PHP docs "Not all conversion specifiers may be supported by your C library, in which case they will not be supported by PHP's strftime(). Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, so your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This means that %e, %T, %R and, %D (and possibly others) - as well as dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 - will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems."

Comment: @user3227275 to give an answer use the answer section, comments are for asking for the details etc.

Comment: It's calculated and not  retrieved from DB.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the servers timezone.
The timestamp `0` is equal to `1970-01-01 00:00:00` in UTC.

You can try this to see the difference:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); // UTC -8
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 0);
// Gives: 1969-12-31 16:00:00

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 0);
// Gives: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/8PGQL

The site you used seem to be french and France is UTC +1, which means that `0` is the same as `1970-01-01 01:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

The server time zone of this website is UTC + 1

The website default language is french and Paris time zone is UTC +1 and that makes sense.